# How to add a short text in math-mode keeping spaces between words

Tags: math-mode, spacing, text

I am writing the following:

```
$$p(Z_{n+m}=i for some m> 0|Z_{n}=i)=1$$
```

Compiling, the spaces between the words "i for some m" are removed giving as a result "iforsomem"

How can I prevent this?

Note that I cannot write something like

```
$p(Z_{n+m}=i$ for some $m> 0|Z_{n}=i)=1$
```

because I want it centered horizontally

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use `\usepackage{amsmath}` and then you can have `\text{ for some }` or simply use (without `amsmath`) `\mbox{ for some }`

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Comment: Both ways did work. Thank you @Au101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

in your document and then you can type

```
\begin{equation*}
\text{$p(Z_{n+m}=i$ for some $m>0 \mid Z_{n}=i)=1$}
\end{equation*}
```